# Passar variavel com varios input/select

Tags: php, html

Tenho um formulario com varios input que crio com um ciclo for, que passo por POST para outra pagina e altero o seu nome como no exemplo:

```
<form action="page2.php" method="post">
<?php 
    for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++){ 
?>
<select name=fichier<?php echo $i?> > (...)
```

O problema é caso não quero preencher a input ou select, como faço para receber o seu valor? Para não tar a repetir codigo para os varios inpuut tenho isto na outra pagina que recebe o POST.

```
for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++){
    if (isset($_POST['fichier'.$i])) 
    {
        $fichier = htmlentities($_POST['fichier'.$i]);
    }

    if(isset($_POST['fichier'.$i])== 0){
        break;
    }
    //echo $fichier;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode nomear os inputs com colchetes no final, Ex:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST)) {
    var_dump($_POST);
}

?>

<form method="post">
    <input id="itens[]" name="itens[]" value="text1" type="text" /><br>
    <input id="itens[]" name="itens[]" value="text2" type="text" /><br>
    <input id="itens[]" name="itens[]" value="text3" type="text" /><br>
    <input id="itens[]" name="itens[]" value="text4" type="text" /><br>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**Saída:**

```
array (size=1)
  'itens' => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string 'text1' (length=5)
      1 => string 'text2' (length=5)
      2 => string 'text3' (length=5)
      3 => string 'text4' (length=5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Como você tem um formulário com vários `input`, e nao quer repetir os valores a solução seria inserir um nome com `[]` no final para que os valores sejam salvos em um array.

Exemplo:

**page.html**

```
<form action="page2.php" method="post">
   Input1 <input id="fichier[]" name="fichier[]" type="text" /><br>
   Input2 <input id="fichier[]" name="fichier[]" type="text" /><br>
   Input3 <input id="fichier[]" name="fichier[]" type="text" /><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

**page2.php**

```
<?php 
    if (isset($_POST['fichier'])) {
        var_dump($_POST['fichier']);
    }   
 ?>
```

Saida apos POST:

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(6) "texto1" [1]=> string(6) "texto2" [2]=> string(6) "texto3" }
```